# Issue aligning tikz object to the document coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, math-operators

I am having difficulty to align an array of thick lines with the coordinates of the document.

The issue can be seen in the following picture. The black boxes should be perfectly aligned with the grid lines in the document. The math formula I used in the macro `\arrayBox` does not seem to have any issue to align them. Could someone kindly help me with that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10mm, letterpaper]{standalone}
\newcommand{\singleBox}[4] % Upper-left corner coordinates (#1,#2), (length,width)=#3,#4
{
    \draw[line width=#4 mm] (#1mm,#2mm-#4 mm *1.0/2.0) -- (#1 mm + #3 mm,#2mm-#4 mm *1.0/2.0);
}

\newcommand{\arrayBox}[6] % Array of single boxes with the spacing between them and the number of boxes needed
{
    \foreach \a in {0,1,...,#6} {
        \def\x{#3 mm + #5 mm}
        \singleBox{#1 mm + \x *\a}{#2}{#3}{#4}
    }

}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \foreach \b in {1,2,...,40} {
          \draw[line width=0.1pt] (\b mm,0) -- (\b mm,30mm);
       }
       \foreach \b in {1,2,...,15} {
          \draw[line width=0.1pt] (0,\b mm) -- (210mm,\b mm);
       }
       \arrayBox{1}{1}{1}{1}{2}{4}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have simplified the code of my answer to make it easier to read and understand.

Comment: @AndréC: great solution! Educational for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of drawing lines of different thicknesses, I only work on the grid coordinates. This simplifies all calculations.

To do this, I modified the `\singleBox` macro by filling the box with the coordinates of the diagonal north-west of this box:

```
\newcommand{\singleBox}[4] % Upper-left corner coordinates (#1,#2), (length,depth)=#3,#4
{ \fill(#1mm,#2mm) rectangle (#1 mm + #3 mm,#2mm-#4 mm);
}
```

I also modified the `\arrayBox` macro so that pgf does the coordinate calculations in the loop and not outside:

```
\newcommand{\arrayBox}[6] % Array of single boxes with the spacing between them and the number of boxes needed
{   \foreach \a [evaluate=\a as \debut using (#1+(#3+#5)*\a)] in {0,1,...,#6}   { \singleBox{\debut}{#2}{#3}{#4}
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: screenshot]

With the full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm, letterpaper]{standalone}
\newcommand{\singleBox}[4] % Upper-left corner coordinates (#1,#2), (length,depth)=#3,#4
{
   % \draw[line width=#4 mm] (#1mm,#2mm-#4 mm/2) -- (#1 mm + #3 mm,#2mm-#4 mm/2);
    \fill(#1mm,#2mm) rectangle (#1 mm + #3 mm,#2mm-#4 mm);
}

\newcommand{\arrayBox}[6] % Array of single boxes with the spacing between them and the number of boxes needed
{   \foreach \a [evaluate=\a as \debut using (#1+(#3+#5)*\a)] in {0,1,...,#6}   { \singleBox{\debut}{#2}{#3}{#4}
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \foreach \b in {1,2,...,29} {
          \draw[line width=0.1pt] (\b mm,0) -- (\b mm,16mm);
       }
       \foreach \b in {1,2,...,15} {
          \draw[line width=0.1pt] (0,\b mm) -- (30mm,\b mm);
       }
        \arrayBox{1}{1}{1}{1}{2}{4}
        \arrayBox{0}{4}{3}{2}{3}{4}


    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```