# Repeating boxes vertically in defined distances

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\newsavebox{\recA}
\savebox{\recA}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{1.618*.88}
\draw [thick, black, fill=red] (0,0) rectangle +(1,\incrmnt);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newsavebox{\recB}
\savebox{\recB}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{1.618*.88*2}
\draw [thick, black, fill=red] (0,0) rectangle +(1,\inc);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\foreach \X in {1,3,5,7}
{\node[blue] (y-\X) at (0,\X){\usebox{\recB}};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\foreach \X in {1,...,4}
{\node[blue] (y-\X) at (0,\X){\usebox{\recA}};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produced the following diagram. It depends on the scaling and the foreach sequence; which does not give me precise control over the vertical and horizontal spacing between the boxes.

[image]

I would like to repeat the rectangles in precise vertical spacing to look like the following diagram.

[image]

Comment: What’s the difference? Can you elaborate more on what are you looking for. You already have rectangles stacked vertically.

Comment: I am trying to control the precise vertical and horizontal  spaces between the boxes. The code I used does not do that. It only depends on the scaling and the foreach sequence. This does not give me precise control.

Comment: Look here, there's a similar problem if I'm not mistaken: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/501575/138900